# Running Android Studio on an ARM Surface Pro X

Tags: android, arm

Does Android Studio run on a Microsoft Surface Pro X – 13" that has an ARM processor?

I am seeing conflicting information on my searches.

Other specs:

- Standing screen display size  ‎13 Inches
- Max Screen Resolution ‎1 Pixels
- Processor ‎8032
- RAM   ‎16 GB LPDDR4
- Graphics Coprocessor  ‎ARM Mali T604
- Chipset Brand ‎Qualcomm
- Card Description  ‎Integrated

Comment: Android studio runs like crap on 8gb even if you can get it to work.  I KNOW.  It doesn't actually answer your question but I can tell you now.  Both Linux and Windows on an Intel processor SUCKED on an 8gb system.  I wrote android code for over a year.  A continual virtual memory pound on my disk.  I am assuming that the people at google have WAY MORE memory than that.

Comment: Android Studio, in order to support the Android Emulator, requires Intel HAXM, which your ARM processor cannot support. You really should work on including an actual question, in the body of the question, and use a more descriptive question title.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas it seems OP has the 16GB version going by the specs they give. I suspect the bigger problem may be the 1 pixel screen resolution though.

Comment: @Ramhound HAXM is discontinued by Intel. In Android SDK HAXM is already marked as deprecated. And HAXM was never necessary to run Android emulator, it was only necessary to make it run more smooth.

Comment: you do not need Intel HAXM to run the emulator. HAXM only makes sense when your processor is also intel.

Also there's a banner at the top of the Android studio downloads page that reads "Note: Windows machines with ARM-based CPUs aren't currently supported."

Comment: @Mokubai, you are correct.  The initial post which OP has wonderfully updated was confusing.  It looked like 8gb ram with 16gb video ram (which makes no sense).  The current post is much clearer! :) Thanks OP!!.  16gb is plenty to work with Android Studio.  Not sure about ARM so I need to bow out to smarter people than myself.

Answer (score 1):

At least it's [not officially supported](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-install-android-studio#1).

For Windows system requirements this page says:

```
x86_64 CPU architecture; 2nd generation Intel Core or newer, or AMD CPU with support for a Windows Hypervisor
```

You have neither (not x86_64 nor AMD).

Also there is no Windows ARM build in the [downloads](https://developer.android.com/studio) (please scroll down). So you'd have to run the x64 version in emulation mode.

Windows 11 on ARM can emulate x86 and also x64 apps without additional programs ([link](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/12/10/introducing-x64-emulation-in-preview-for-windows-10-on-arm-pcs-to-the-windows-insider-program/)). And theoretically there are Android ARM images for the virtual Android devices.

But because Android Studio is a complex and big software I think it's not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm also looking into using cloud IDE. BTW, the specs were copied off whatever was posted on Amazon, so my apologies for incorrect/inaccurate info.